# How to catch stderr in a composite command?

Tags: java, linux, bash, ffmpeg

Say I have a linux command running from a java code:

```
/bin/bash -c nice -n 8 ffmpeg {params of ffmpeg} & echo $! > ffmpeg.pid
```

In java I want to catch stderr of ffmpeg:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
while (...) {
    String ffmpegStdErrLine = input.readLine();
    ...
}
```

That's not about ffmpeg but how can I make sure I'm reading ffmpeg's StdErr?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Java would replace bash as the process manager. Instead of having bash start the process in the background and writing a pid file, you would have Java start the process in the background and optionally control it through the `Process` instance.

```
Process process = 
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "nice", "-n", "8", "ffmpeg", "-i", "file.avi", "output.avi" });

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
while (...) {
    String ffmpegStdErrLine = input.readLine();
    ...
}
```

If you later want to e.g. kill it, instead of `kill $(< ffmpeg.pid)`, you would use `process.destroy()`.

PS: Never use `Runtime.exec(String)`. It's error prone and doesn't behave like C's `system(3)` at all. Always use `Runtime.exec(String[])`.

Comment: The `process.destroy()` is not always enough to kill ffmpeg as it is sending SIGTERM. Most of the time the best way to kill ffmpeg is kill -9 (SIGKILL).